# Hash Function Formating Question

Tags: hash

If a hash function is written:

```
Hash(Hello||World)
```

Is that equivalent to `Hash(Hello) +  Hash(World)` or `Hash(HelloWorld)` ?

Similarly, is there any difference between `Hash(Hello||World)` and `Hash(Hello,World)`?

Answer (score 2):

Typically, the notation `||` means concatenation, which is to say `Hello||World` is equivalent to `HelloWorld`.

### Is that equivalent to `Hash(Hello) +  Hash(World)` or `Hash(HelloWorld)`?

So `Hash(Hello||World)` is equivalent to `Hash(HelloWorld)`.

### Is there any difference between `Hash(Hello||World)` and `Hash(Hello,World)`?

This depends entirely on what `Hello,World` is defined to mean.

Notation does not have absolutely defined meaning - what a symbol means in one context can be different from what that symbol means in another context.

The only way to know for sure is to check the definitions of the notation from wherever you found this.

If there are no such definitions, then it is safe to assume the most common/obvious meaning for the notation. However, if the notation is non-standard, then there may not be a common and obvious meaning for it.

Comment: Typically if $H$ is some kind of ‘hash function’, $H(r, m)$ means the hash of _some_ unique encoding of the tuple $(r, m)$ so that hashing `Hello` and `World` doesn't coincide with hashing `Hell` and `oWorld`, which may be $r \mathbin\| m$ if $r$ is fixed-length, or may actually fail to be unique leading to collisions in the hash if you're a [Swiss election authority](https://people.eng.unimelb.edu.au/vjteague/HowNotToProveElectionOutcome.pdf#page=9).

Answer (score -2):

I think you are confusing hash functions with homomorphic encryption.
No, you cannot combine separate hash results mathematically (add, xor, etc.) and expect the same result. Any hash worth its salt will not allow that. Otherwise, it would be trivial to break the hash with lookup tables of partial results.

Comment: It's really unclear what part of the question "No" is an answer to.